# Sticky Footer with inner elements with paddings and margins (Ryan Fait)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I just can't wrap my head around, it might be because that I'm tired. I'm using [Ryan's Fait sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) which I'm sure the most of you are familiar with. I use it regularly and never had any problems with it until now. The design that I'm working has a footer with several inner child elements.

One of the elements `.newsletter` is using padding or margins to make a wide gap so that a background image can be placed on the body. This is causing a overflow even when entering the correct height. Deleting the padding corrects the problem. I know that using `overflow: hidden` is an option but I'd rather find out the cause.

*Screenshot with margins or padding set within the news letter element:*

[image: Sticky Footer Not Working with padding]

*Screen without margins or padding set in the news letters:*

[image]

*Not working CSS:*

```
body {
  background: #212121;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100%;
}

.maincontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -424px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainfooter, .push {
  height: 424px;
  width: 100%;
}

.newsletter {
  padding: 1.875rem 0 1.875rem;
}

.newsletter-fix {
  background: #000;
  padding: 3rem 0 1rem;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

*Working CSS:*

Simply changing the following values from those mentioned above to the following resolves the issue but I want the padding, or margin gap between the newsletter.

```
.maincontainer {
  margin: 0 auto -394px;
}

.mainfooter, .push {
  height: 394px;
}

.newsletter {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to help you with the HTML code. Anyway, try `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: you mean `box-sizing:border-box` didnt fix the problem?

Comment: yea, no luck. I put `box-sizing: border-box;` into `.mainfooter{}`, should also note the site is using Zurb Foundation 5 so it has some box-sizing already using after, and before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that I'm extremely tried and stupid! I thank everyone for taking the time to take a look but it seems its as simple as a user error.

The problem was because I was counting from the very first bit of colour, in this case `background: #000` on the `.newsletterfix` and not taking into consideration of the invisible padding above it. Stupid, me.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What if you put `background-color : black` to your `.mainfooter` instead of putting the background-color to the different element inside your footer?

Comment: I want the background from `body {}` to be visible, it will be an image. So using any solid colour in the footer will block the view. The solution I'm after is a fix that will allow to use padding, or margin within the footer, otherwise I'd just remove the padding :)

Comment: I don't get it. You are already using solid color in the 2 element inside your mainfooter

Comment: No, the footer newsletter element uses #000, the body background uses #212121. The footer doesn't use any colour.

Comment: Your .lowermenu uses #000 too. So every element of your footer is #000, how do you expect the background from body to be visible ?

Comment: Sorry buy your very mistaken. `.newsletter` and `.copyright` elements are not contained within `.lowermenu`.... So why would they share the same background?